# $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure, measuring supp($f$)

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let (X,$\mu$) be a measure space and $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure.  There is some A such that $\mu$(supp($f_n$))$\leq$A for all n, show $\mu$(supp($f$))$\leq$A.

Studying qual exams and came across this one.  Fair to assume $f_n:X\rightarrow \mathbb(R)$, but I'm curious about cases where $f_n(x)\rightarrow f $ in measure and let g=1 on a set outside of the support of f on set of measure 0 with a nonzero closure (like 1 on rationals and 0 otherwise assuming X is a subset of real numbers). therefore $f_n\rightarrow f+g$ in measure, but the support of f+g would be greater than the support of f and could be greater than the support of $f_n$ (and thus A).

Can someone help me figure out what the issue is?

Comment: how did you define the support ? Because in my lecture we did have to different definitions, for simple functions the support have just been $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ while later for stokes and co we said it is $\overline{f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})}$. Which one is yours ?

Comment: I've always understood the support to be the closure.  If it's not treated as such then the problem isn't that bad.  If it is then I'm not sure if this is even a possible question.

Comment: For convergence in measure, $X$ need only be a measure space, no topology required.  So (of course) there is no closure in the definition of "support".

Answer (score 1):

In the context of measure spaces, the support of $f$ usually just means $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus 0)$, i.e. simply the set of inputs giving nonzero outputs.  Since at this point we haven't specified any topology on $X$, it doesn't make sense to talk about closure.

Here is a hint to get you started: for any $k,n$, we have
$$\{|f| > 1/k\} \subset \{ |f_n| > 1/2k\} \cup \{ |f_n - f| > 1/2k\}.$$